# Tkz-Euclide: mark segment: mark thickness

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Is there a way to control the thickness of the mark using `\tkzMarkSegment` in `tkz-euclide`? (Or are there other readily-available macros with such options?)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);

\draw (A)--(B);
\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354941/how-to-change-tkzdrawsegments-marks-style

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify `line width`  of marks  within a `scope`  environment

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);

\draw (A)--(B);
\begin{scope}[line width=2pt]
\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,B)
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```